# How do I get the 'BOOKS' to be vertically aligned in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I cant seem to get the BOOKS to vertically align in the middle when I added `vertical-align: middle;` but I must be missing something? Can someone please help me out.

http://jsfiddle.net/wz9xzu2v/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `vertival-align:middle` to `img` tag.

```
#menu ul > li img {
    display: inline;
    border: 1px;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle; // <- added this
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wz9xzu2v/5/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also provide line-height of equal height of that image height to that specific

. it will put your text in center vertically.

```
li.img-text {line-height:35px;}
```